# Can I recover an Oracle database to an instance with a different SID?

Tags: oracle

I've implemented a backup (and recovery) plan for an Oracle 11gR2 database as follows:

1. Installed the same version of 11gR2 on production and disaster recovery (DR) servers
2. Created identical Oracle instances (filesystem structures, SID, etc.) on both servers
3. Every 6 hours I'm performing a hot backup on the production system and copying the files to the DR system:

`alter database begin backup;`
`<copy all data files to DR server>`
`alter database end backup;`
`alter system archive log current;`
`alter database backup controlfile to 'c:\temp\control01.ctl';`
`alter database backup controlfile to trace as 'c:\temp\create_control.sql';`
`<copy both control files to DR server>`
`<copy all archived logs to DR server>`

4. When I want to recover on the DR system I can simply make sure all the files are in the correct places, "startup mount", "recover automatic database until cancel using backup controlfile;", and "alter database open resetlogs".  At this point I only need to change a few dba passwords and the database is usable.

My question/concern is that I need to support multiple instances on the DR server, all of which will be recovering from the production site (they are basically additional test instances).  Rather than expdp/impdp I'd like to use my above process as it is much faster than an import.

Can I do it?  Only 1 instance on the DR server can have the same SID as the production server.  Also, the file system paths are different for all but 1 of the instances on the DR server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible - see http://www.shutdownabort.com/quickguides/clone_rman.php
this might have some useful info too http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10734/rcmrecov.htm#1009919

EDIT without RMAN:
see http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_db_copy.htm

EDIT 2 without RMAN:
http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Backup_and_Recovery/BandR_2.shtml

Comment: Interesting, but can I do it without RMAN?

Comment: yes you can, you "just" need to change some more - esp. pfile/spfile need some changes to make sure that the "clone" is a different instance... we did it this way sometime in the "far" past... not sure if I remember all the steps correctly...found it - see my edit

Comment: found another way - so 1 with RMAN and 2 ways without RMAN and last but not least the option with export/import...